# Javascript append element with special characters

Tags: javascript, html

I'm appending to a div some HTML code which might include special characters (UTF-8).

I'm doing this:

```
ad_status = '<span style="color:orange;"><strong>Para Aprovação</strong></span>';
$('#meus-anuncios').append(ad_status);
```

I have the meta for utf-8 in my html file already. Any idea that I could use?

Comment: What you're doing doesn't work? If not, how does it fail?

Comment: Isn't that working? It should be. Maybe you're missing a server-side header.

Comment: No it appears like this 'Para Aprova��o'

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/3x6Pn/

Comment: Perhaps your javascript file is delivered with a wrong charset?

Comment: i already tried that... changed my IDE configuration... but it didn't work... maybe i am doing it wrong

Comment: @pedrotorres the IDE configuration likely doesn't matter. What matters is the charset that the server sends. Please investigate the network headers for the javascript file.

Comment: @JanDvorak The encoding the file is saved with also matters. If it's saved as latin 1 and served as UTF8, it will break.

Comment: @bfavaretto That's what I'm starting to think happens here.

Comment: Make sure you're saving the file as utf8. That's something you should be able to set from your IDE. Then make sure you're serving the file as utf8 too. That's a webserver configuration, which usually can be overridden from your server-side language of choice. This might help: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding, and http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html

Comment: im checking my request, and its going with "charset=utf-8" but the response has "charset=ISO-8859-1"... am i allowed to change this?

Comment: Yes, what server side language are you using?

Comment: i am using PHP. but this string with special character is created in the javascript file. its all client-side.

Comment: That's weird. You may need to tweak your webserver settings. But before trying into that, try just `<script src="myscripts.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>`. And again, make sure the js file is saved as utf8.

Comment: well it seem that filezilla wasn't sending my files as UTF-8. thank you guys

Comment: Check the HTTP headers. The Apache AddDefaultCharset setting could need tweaking/disabling.